# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "Id" not found during testing with H2 Database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, h2

I have a class that uses a Hibernate session to call a stored procedure via a JPA @NamedNativeQuery using an in memory H2 database for testing (the actual database is MySQL).  The stored procedure inserts a record into a database table and then returns that row.

However during testing, on converting to the JPA @Entity, I am seeing an H2 database error: **org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "Id" not found**.

I've documented a cut down version of the code below.

As far as I can tell I think it has something to do with the H2 interpretation of the @Id annotation, but don't understand why, so any help would be gratefully appreciated...

**NB - I have searched Stack overflow fairly extensively, including the issue relating to the use of double quotes for column specification, but don't think that this relates to my situation...**

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE History.Status_Report (
Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Unique_Users INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Id) 
);
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE History.Status_Reporting(reporting_date DATE)           
BEGIN     
INSERT INTO history.status_report (Unique_Users) VALUES (10);
SELECT *      FROM History.Status_Report WHERE Id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END;
```

**Entity**
    package com.test;

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;

@NamedNativeQuery(name = "callStatusReporting", query = "CALL Status_Reporting(:reporting_date)", resultClass = StatusReportEntity.class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "Status_Report", catalog = "History")
public class StatusReportEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Id")
    protected Integer id;
    @Column(name = "Unique_Users")
    protected int uniqueUsers;

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public int getUniqueUsers() {
        return this.uniqueUsers;
    }
}
```

**Class under test**

```
package com.test;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class MyListener {

    public StatusReportEntity doRequest(Date reportDate) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession(); // returns a MySQL session or H2 if testing…        
        try {
            Query query = session.getNamedQuery("callStatusReporting").setParameter("reporting_date", reportDate);;
            StatusReportEntity statusReportEntity = (StatusReportEntity) query.uniqueResult();
            return statusReportEntity;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } finally {
            session.close();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**H2 Aliases**

To enable testing using H2, There is also a file to specify the necessary aliases:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS History;
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS Status_Reporting FOR "com.test.StoredProcs.statusReporting";
```

**Test Class to be used by Alias**

And a test class to return a default result from the SP call:

```
package com.test;

import com.test.StatusReportEntity;

public class StoredProcs {

    public static StatusReportEntity statusReporting(Date reportingDate) {
        StatusReportEntity statusReportEntity = StatusReportEntity.builder().withId(1).withUniqueUsers(10).build();
        return statusReportEntity;
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
package com.test;

import com.test.MyListener;
import java.util.Calendar;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MyListenerTest {

    private MyListener listener;

    @Test
    public void listenerReturnsLatestData() throws Exception {
        MyListener myListener = new MyListener();
        assertNotNull(myListener.statusReporting(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do proper formatting of your question and please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804321/org-h2-jdbc-jdbcsqlexception-column-id-not-found

Comment: Hi, your code formatting is screwed. Good formatting increases the likelihood that someone will read and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE TABLE PERSON(
        PERSON_ID IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
        GIVEN_NAME VARCHAR(20),
        FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(20),MIDDLE_NAME VARCHAR(20),
        LAST_NAME VARCHAR(20),TITLE VARCHAR(20),NAME_SUFFIX VARCHAR(20));`

```
The entity class must use any Generation strategy.
```

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)

@Column(name ="PERSON_ID")
private int personId;
```